# Не могу удалить элемент input из списка — всегда удаляется последний?

Tags: vue.js

Ссылку на код прикрепляю, в общем дело такое если в поля ввести числа 1,2,3,4 и удалим первый элемент то удалится последний. Как эту ситуацию исправить?

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    delete1: function(){
        this.todos.splice(0, 1);
    },
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ztoqf456/

Comment: Это всё неправда. Удаляется так, как и должно   ....... https://jsfiddle.net/Lvj67hcm/

Comment: введи по моей ссылке значения 1,2,3,4 и удали первый элемент

Comment: Нет, это ты перейди по моей ссылке и начни удалять элементы

Comment: В твоём случае ты никак не взаимодействешь с данными, поэтому твой код невалиден в приницпе только лишь вбив текст в инпуты.

Comment: ну тогда почему когда я удаляю тег с элементом инпут внутри введенный текст не удаляется, он ведь должен по логике удалиться? в итоге значение просто "переходит" как бы к другому. Мне эта логика вообще не понятна и по моему мнению она совершенно абсурдна. Что за треш то такой творится

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать для циклов специальный атрибут [key](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/api/special-attributes.html)

> Специальный атрибут `key` в первую очередь нужен в качестве подсказки для Vue и его алгоритма виртуального DOM для идентификации VNode при сравнениях обновлённого списка узлов со старым. Без ключей Vue использует алгоритм, который минимизирует перемещения элементов и по-максимуму будет стараться изменять/переиспользовать элементы одного типа. При использовании ключей элементы будут переупорядочиваться в соответствии с изменением порядка следования ключей, а элементы, чьи ключи уже отсутствуют, будут всегда удаляться/уничтожаться.

В текущем случае можно сделать хоть так

```
<li v-for="(todo, i) in todos" :key="todo">
```

хоть так

```
<li v-for="(todo, i) in todos" :key="todo.text">
```

чтобы Vue мог однозначно идентифицировать запись